# How to add todo details to my todo List in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angular js project to make todolist application.But I am stuck at place where I Want to add my todo details to todoList but I am getting error.

Requrirement to declare property in adddetails and then call service method save item to add todo details to service list

Here is my code:

**Error getting is**

> KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) AngularJS Unit Test should call saveitem method of service while adding new item FAILED
>
> ReferenceError: Myservice is not defined
>           at Object.$scope.saveitem (app/scripts/controllers/main.js:9:619)
>           at UserContext. (test/spec/controllers/main.js:118:12)
>
> Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 13 of 16 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.064 secs)
>
> [1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) AngularJS Unit Test should display the selected item when clicked on edit button FAILED
>
> Expected spy getitem to have been called with [ 1 ] but it was never called.
>    at UserContext. (test/spec/controllers/main.js:148:17)
>
> Expected [ Object({ id: 0, name: '', age: 0, mobile: 0 }) ] to equal Object({ name: 'one', age: 2, mobile: 3333333333, id: 1 }).
>   at UserContext. (test/spec/controllers/main.js:149:30)
>
> Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 14 of 16 (2 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.07 secs)
>
> [1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) AngularJS Unit Test should update the arraylist after edit & save FAILED
>
> ReferenceError: Myservice is not defined
>           at Object.$scope.saveitem (app/scripts/controllers/main.js:9:619)
>           at UserContext. (test/spec/controllers/main.js:191:12)
>
> Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 15 of 16 (3 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.074 secs)
>
> [1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) AngularJS Unit Test should delete the selected item when clicked on delete button FAILED
>
> Expected spy deleteitem to have been called with [ 1 ] but it was never called.
>           at UserContext. (test/spec/controllers/main.js:238:17)
>
> Expected 3 to be 2.
>           at UserContext. (test/spec/controllers/main.js:239:45)
>
> Expected 1 to be 2.
>           at UserContext. (test/spec/controllers/main.js:241:42)
>
> Expected Object({ name: 'two', age: 2, mobile: 2222222222, id: 2 }) to be undefined.
>           at UserContext. (test/spec/controllers/main.js:242:39)
>
> Expected $.length = 3 to equal 2.
>
> Expected $[1].name = 'one' to equal 'two'.
>
> Expected $[1].age = 1 to equal 2.
>
> Expected $[1].mobile = 3333333333 to equal 2222222222.
>
> Expected $[1].id = 1 to equal 2.
>
> Expected $[2] = Object({ name: 'two', age: 2, mobile: 2222222222, id: 2 }) to equal undefined.
>           at UserContext. (test/spec/controllers/main.js:243:36)
>
> Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 16 of 16 (4 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.079 secs)
>
> [1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 16 of 16 (4 FAILED) (0.104 secs / 0.079 secs)

**index.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// define controller here
myApp.controller('MainController',["$scope", 'MyService', function($scope,MyService) {

$scope.init = function () {
  MyService.list();    
}
$scope.adddetail = [
  {
  id:0,
  name:'',
  age:0,
  mobile:0,
 } ];

  // define "init" function
      // call 'list' method of service
      // define "adddetail" property
$scope.saveitem = function () {
Myservice.saveitem();
}

$scope.edititem = function () {

}

$scope.deleteitem = function () {

}

  // define "saveitem" function
      // call 'saveitem' method of service
      // clear ng-model after saved

  // define "edititem" function
      // call 'getitem' method of service

  // define "deleteitem" function
      // call 'deleteitem' method of service

  // call "init" function

}]);
```

```
// define MyService here
myApp.service('MyService', function () {

  //unique  id
  var uid = 1;

  //arraylist to hold all items
  var arraylist;
  this.arraylist = [{
    id: 0,
    'name': 'Rahul',
    'age': 21,
    'mobile': 8866774455
  }];

   this.saveitem = function () {    
            if($scope.arraylist === undefined){
                return false ;
            }
            else{

                $scope.todoObj = {};
                $scope.todoObj["uid"] = $scope.todo;

                $scope.todolist.push($scope.todoObj);
                $scope.arraylist = [];
            }    
}

   this.getitem= function () {
   }

   this.deleteitem= function () {
   }
   this.list= function () {
   }

  // define 'saveitem' function
      // add a new item in arraylist (hint: add new item with id)
      // update existing item from arraylist (hint: edit existing item by id)

  // define 'getitem' function
      //get particular item by id from arraylist

  // define 'deleteitem' function
      // delete selected item from arraylist

  // define 'list' function
      // return arraylist    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here:

> ReferenceError: **Myservice** is not defined
>
> at Object.**$scope.saveitem** (app/scripts/controllers/main.js:9:619)

error caused by a typo(MyService is the correct service name):

```
$scope.saveitem = function () {
    MyService.saveitem();
}
```